# How to call only a part of the procedure into another vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I've a script named `script 1` that creates a text file and stores some string values into it.
I need to call this script `script 1` into another script file named `script 2` but only part of it (script 1). I don't want to call the part of the script (script 1) that will store string values.

How can I call only part of the `script 1` into `script 2`? I'm using TestComplete to run these scripts.

Comment: If you need help with your code, show your code.  Though I suspect what you actually need is a function library with a common function for creating the text file which script 1 calls, and then adds string values, and that script 2 can call to create a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some parameter in `script 1` which you can check every time before storing some values in file

```
function script1(flag)
    ----create text file---
    if flag<>false then
        --stores some string values--
    end if
end function

function script2
    Call script1(false)
end function
```

If you can't make any changes like passing some parameter in `script1`(as it might be called from other scripts also and then you will have to change signature everywhere), then you can create a global variable and before calling it from `script2`, assign some value in that variable and check that value in script1.

```
dim flag=true

function script1()
    ----create text file---
    if flag<>false then
        --stores some string values--
    end if
end function

function script2()
    flag=false
    call script1()
    flag=true
end function
```

Hope this solves your problem. Otherwise, share some sample code so that I can understand the scenario better.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, you can execute all of the "body" content or you can cut some lines or whatever you need.

You put Both files in the same folder

This is the content of Script1.vbs

```
a=5
msgbox "hello world"
b=3
msgbox cstr(a*b)
```

This is the content of Script2.vbs

```vbs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(".\script1.vbs",1,FALSE)
ts.ReadLine
body = ts.ReadLine
ts.Close
Execute body
```